# Internet Explorer 7 menu dropdown under other elements problem

Tags: html, css

As you can see in http://btbexpress.com/

In internet explorer 7, the top horizontal menu displays the subcategories under the div tags on the page. The menu's items are either positioned relative or absolute and the z-index is higher than the div tags'. How do I make the dropdowns appear in front of everything else in the page then ?

Comment: Setting z-index to something higher than anything else on the page should work without issues. However I did notice that the menus only show up the first time you roll over them - after rolling out the menu simply doesn't come back.

Comment: the z-index is set to 10000 ! the news containers are set to 0 but sill no luck..I know they act this way-there's a javascript that requires you to click on them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed using this workaround: http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Answer (score 2):

ul.dropdown has z-index set to 10000 (line 28 of dropdown.css) but isn't positioned. z-index affects only positioned elements (relative, absolute and fixed)

Edit:

I'm not used to deal with table-based layout, but if you still don't see submenu I suppose you need also set an `overflow :visible` somewhere (especially on table cell I guess...)

Comment: overflow:visible is used when content goes out of the area (div or td) and is cut. This is not the case - you can clearly see the dropdown, but its behind the content

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working as you expect, because the entire site is made out of tables.

IE has a `z-index` issue, start by setting your lowest `z-index: 1;`.

Then re-write the site to use semantic div/css layout, then it will work more as you desire.

Also, Вие сте български?

Comment: as I've already said - the problem's fixed with a simple div tag...
an Yes-I'm bulgarian